# Do programs themselves use symbolic links, or are they just for users?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, symlink

For example, when I type `python` it runs python2 because for me, `/usr/bin/python` is linked to `/usr/bin/python2.7`

But does this affect programs? If there are programs on my system that need python 2, and I change `/usr/bin/python` to be linked to python 3 instead of 2, would those programs break?

Or do programs not use things in  `/usr/bin`? I would expect that they don't, since `/usr/bin` seems to be meant just for user commands, but I want to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are programs that need Python 2, they should be explicitly using `/usr/bin/python2` (or similar) instead of the plain `/usr/bin/python`. However, there might be some that haven't been updated, and still use `/usr/bin/python`. Those could very well break.

If you're on Ubuntu 20.04 or newer, the [`python-is-python3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python3) explicitly makes `/usr/bin/python` be Python 3. On older releases, I wouldn't recommend changing that symlink.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!